# In Python Asyncio/Aiohttp, is there an equivalent to NGINX's "client_header_timeout"?

Tags: python, nginx, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In Nginx there's the very handy [client_header_timeout](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_timeout) directive that forces the client to finish sending the headers of an HTTP request within a certain timespan. This is useful to mitigate slowloris attacks in combination with other directives. Is there an equivalent for Python Asyncio/Aiohttp? All I can find in the docs is the [ClientTimeout structure](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientTimeout) that however is only useful for socket-level timeouts like connection establishment or socket reads.